# Customize the print header/footer output for HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

Is there a way to customize the text that is printed on the header and footer of every HTML page that you print, where the page number, URL, date, etc is printed ? (if you choose to print the headers and the footer from the print options).

The other solutions to display a header and a footer on every print page (using thead/tfoot and fixed positioned divs) don't seem to work on Chrome.

Here are the print headers and footers highlighted on a print preview for google.com:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@media screen {
  .print {
      display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  .print {
      display: block;
  }
}
```

And add the .print class to the appropriate element or elements.

Comment: I know how to style elements on page differently for print. I've updated the question with an image to make myself clearer.